# submitting a form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have created a very simple form in laravel..

```
<?php
    echo Form::selectRange('number', 2, 12);
    echo Form::submit('Click Me!');
?>
```

However, at this time I am unclear of how to send the selected value of the DDL to the server to perform a task depending on which value is selected. For example, if 3 is selected it would send you to a specific view that would be different than if 4, 5, or 6 was selected. I checked out the documentation and couldn't find the direction I should go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that if you see the posted data, you'll see a field `number` with the value selected in the `input`.
In laravel you access to such variables as

```
$number = Input::get('number');
...
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**
You also need to open and close the form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) }}
    {{ Form::selectRange('number', 2, 12) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Click Me!') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**EDIT2**
Your routes.php should have something like this:

```
Route::post('foo/bar', function()
{
    $number = Input::get('number');
    .....
});
```

Comment: I tried adding: `$number = Input::get('number');` then `echo $number;` There is no output in my HTML. From everything I am looking at, maybe I need to create a controller to handle the logic?

Comment: So, with the code `<?php
  Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')); 
      Form::selectRange('number', 2, 12);
      Form::submit('Click Me!');
  Form::close();
  $number = Input::get('number');
  echo $number;
    ?>` The form no longer shows on the page, any idea why?

Comment: I think I understand you now... First: You have to either echo **every** call to Form or use blade syntax. Second: the `$number = Input::get('number');` code must be inside a function handling the POST request (when you submit the form).  Look at my second edit